# Rotate array in Python

Tags: python

There is this question, 189 Rotate array on Leetcode. [enter link description here](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/) Its statement is "Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative."
To understand it better, here's an example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVUMV.png)

So, My code for this is

```
for _ in range(k):
   j = nums[-1]
   nums.remove(nums[-1])
   nums.insert(0, j)
```

It cannot pass some of the test cases in it.
In the discussion panel, I found a code claiming it got submitted successfully that went like

```
for _ in  range(k):
   nums.insert(0, nums.pop(-1))
```

I would like to know, what is the difference between these two and why my code isn't able to pass some of the test cases.

Comment: `nums.remove(nums[-1])` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this on python shell `[].remove.__doc__`, you'll see the purpose of `list.remove` is to:

> Remove first occurrence of value. Raises ValueError if the value is
> not present.

In your code `nums.remove(nums[-1])` does not remove the last item, but first occurrence of the value of your last item.

E.g.

If you have a list with values `nums = [2, 4, 8, 3, 4]` and if you do `nums.remove(nums[-1])` the content of `nums` becomes `[2, 8, 3, 4]` not `[2, 4, 8, 3]` that you're expecting.

Comment: @ShadowRanger OP has already discovered the correct solution. The question is basically "I would like to know, what is the difference between these two and why my code isn't able to pass some of the test cases.".

Answer (score 1):

Just use slicing:

```
>>> def rotate(l, n):
...     return l[-n:] + l[:-n]
...
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> rotate(lst, 1)
[7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> rotate(lst, 2)
[6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> rotate(lst, 3)
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code  j = nums[-1] and you are trying to insert(0, nums[-1]).

In

```
for _ in  range(k):
   nums.insert(0, nums.pop(-1))
```

inserting other number - (0, nums.pop(-1))

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by [cesarv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17903384/cesarv) is good and simple, but on large arrays numpy will definitely perform better. Consider:

```
np.roll(lst, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` method takes a single element as an argument and removes it's first occurence from the list.

The `pop()` method takes a single argument (index). The argument passed to the method is optional. If not passed, the default index -1 is passed as an argument (index of the last item).

If the test case has the same item before the last index then test case will fail.

Hence to correct your code replace `remove` with `pop`

```
for _ in range(k):
   poppedElement = nums.pop()
   nums.insert(0, poppedElement)
```

or to make it even concise -

```
for _ in range(k):
   nums.insert(0, nums.pop())
```